# Vectorizing PyTorch operation in forward

Tags: python, pytorch, vectorization, conv-neural-network

I wrote this PyTorch Module to take two groups of feature maps outputted by two separate convolution layers and average them. The inputs are two Tensors containing the same number of images with the same number of channels ([batch_size, channels, Height, Width]). The feature maps from the two images are of different sizes.

```py
    class Avg_Combine(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Avg_Combine, self).__init__()
            
        def forward(self, a, b):
            if a.shape[2] < b.shape[2]:
                factor = b.shape[2] / a.shape[2]
                a = functional.interpolate(a, scale_factor=factor)
            elif a.shape[2] > b.shape[2]:
                factor = a.shape[2] / b.shape[2]
                b = functional.interpolate(b, scale_factor=factor)
            
            idx0 = 0
            for img in a:
                idx1 = 0
                for channel_a in img:
                    channel_a = channel_a.add(b[idx0][idx1]) / 2
                    idx1 += 1
                idx0 += 1
        
            return a
```

For example, a=[20, 128, 8, 8], b=[20, 128, 4, 4]. The code will upsample b to match the size of a. Now that a and b are all of the size [20, 128, 8, 8], they are averaged on the "channel" dimension to generate an output of size [20, 128, 8, 8].

However, during training, this function is like 50~100 times slower than a regular CNN with the same layers. I'm suspecting that the for-loop is the cause of the issue. How can I vectorize this operation? Are there any other suggestions on how I can possibly speed this thing up?

Thanks a lot! Any suggestion is appreciated!